# Search a list containing class objects and remove the class object that matches an instance variable of class object

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is in Python 3.3.

So I have two classes: `Employee` and `Zone`. `Zone` takes the `Employee` objects I create and puts their `name` and `ID` into a `list`. I want the `remove_employee` method to take an employee's `ID` in a string, find the employee that matches the `ID`, and remove them from the list. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Employee:
employee_count = 0

    def __init__(self, name, employee_id):
        self._name = name
        self._employee_id = employee_id
        Employee.employee_count += 1

    def get_employee_id(self):
        return self._employee_id


class Zone:

    def __init__(self, name="Kitchen", employees=[]):
        self._name = name
        self._employees = employees

    def add_employee(self, employee):
        self._employees += [employee]

    def remove_employee(self, employee_id):
        for employee_id in self._employees:
            self._employees.remove(employee_id)

    def number_of_employees(self):
        return len(self._employees)
```

And when I try to run this:

```
John = Employee('John', 'F12345')
Jack = Employee('Jack', 'F23514')
Jane = Employee('Jane', 'F10253')
Kitchen = Zone()
Kitchen.add_employee(John)
Kitchen.add_employee(Jack)
Kitchen.add_employee(Jane)
Kitchen.remove_employee('F12345') #John's ID
```

It removes John and Jane from the list, instead of just John. I'm very new to programming and I'm completely stumped by how to write `remove_method()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not the immediate problem, but watch out for that [mutable default argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) on `Zone.__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are iterating over the employees list with

for employee_id in self._employees

and removing the employees.

You should change do something like this instead:

```
def remove_employee(self, employee_id):
    for employee in self._employees:
        if employee.get_employee_id() == employee_id:
            self._employees.remove(employee)
```

or better yet filter! =)

```
def remove_employee(self, employee_id):
        self.employees = list(filter(lambda x: x.get_employee_id() != employee_id))
```

Answer (score 3):

In `remove_employee`, you don't actually check that the employee ID matches the current value in your loop. Also, you shouldn't modify a list you're iterating over; it can cause all sorts of problems. Seems like you intend something like this:

```
def remove_employee(self, employee_id):
    employees = []
    for employee in self._employees:
        if employee._employee_id != employee_id:
            employees.append(employee)
    self._employees = employees
```

which can be significantly shortened with something called a list comprehension:

```
def remove_employee(self, employee_id):
    self._employees = [e for e in self._employees if e._employee_id != employee_id]
```

However, the whole thing would be even simpler if you used the appropriate data structure to store employees, which is a dict, keyed by ID, not a list. For example:

```
class Zone:
    def __init__(self, name="Kitchen", employees=None):
        self._name = name
        self._employees = employees or {}

    def add_employee(self, employee):
        self._employees[employee._employee_id] = employee

    def remove_employee(self, employee_id):
        self._employees.pop(employee_id)

    def number_of_employees(self):
        return len(self._employees)
```

Comment: I think these solutions incurs overhead from creating/appending an additional list. Why not modify the list in-line?

Comment: For the reason I gave: you shouldn't modify a list you're iterating over. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/104349) for a good explanation of why.

Comment: @mattsap: Such small lists aren't going to have a noticeable impact on RAM usage. However, it may be desirable to modify the existing `self._employees` list, rather than replacing it. And that's easily accomplished via slice assignment: `self._employees[:] = employees`.